# Read and print unicode literal string from file in Python 3

Tags: python, unicode

If we want to print symbols of **alpha** and **beta** in Python then one way is:

```
print('\u03b1')
print('\u03b2')
```

Output:

```
α
β
```

What I wish to do is to write the unicode for these symbols in a file: **data.txt** , read the file and then print the symbols.

**data.txt**

```
03b1
03b2
```

So, I tried

```
file = open('data.txt')
for word in file:
    greek_word = '\\u' + word
    print(greek_word)
```

However, I got the output as:

```
\u03b1

\u03b2
```

I am not able to figure out how to print **\u03b1** into **α**. I have read through unicode documentation, performed several permutation of encoding, decoding utf-8 etc. but could not succeed.

Python shows type of both variables as **str** only

Comment: What you have is the literal string `\u03b1` rather than the encoded value. Copy and paste the `α` character into your *data.txt* file. Ensure you save the file as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion from `'\u03b1'` to `'α'` happens when the expression is being evaluated. In your case, you are evaluating `'\\u'` and `'03b1'` independently and then just concatenating the result. So they are just appended.

What you actually want is to evaluate the concatenated result. This can be done using built-in `eval` function. This code should work as expected:

```
file = open('data.txt')
for word in file:
    greek_word = '\\u' + word
    print(eval(f"'{greek_word}'"))
```

Here, the concatenated value, `\u03b1` is first quoted, which results in `'\u03b1'`, which is then passes to `eval`, which evaluates it to `'α'` as it would have normally done.

Answer (score 1):

Use `int(hex_string, 16)` to convert the hex representation into the numerical unicode code point, and use `chr()` to turn that into the corresponding character:

```py
file = open('data.txt')
for word in file:
    greek_word = chr(int(word, 16))
    print(greek_word)
```

Note that this only handles single characters, not words, since you didn't specify a format in which complete words should be written in `data.txt`.